# Is it possible to dynamically set the host in SSHHook airflow?

Tags: python, ssh, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I get the parameters from the API to connect to the remote host. They are different every time and I do not know which ones in advance. Can I pass these parameters to SSHHook?
The code is as follows:

```py
    for index, conn in enumerate(get_connections(url=CONFIG.gater_url, vendor=OSS_VENDOR)):
        ssh_hook = SSHHook(
            ssh_conn_id=CONFIG.ssh.ssh_conn_id,
            remote_host=conn.ip,
            username=conn.login,
            password=conn.password,
            port=conn.port
        )
```

Judging by the task logs, it tries to connect to localhost, while in fact the address for connection comes in a different one (this is logged).
In the airflow connections, I removed all the parameters from the ssh connection, leaving only the `conn_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and you do it almost right. Although, you should set `ssh_conn_id=None`. Otherwise, the credentials that you pass as arguments are overwritten by the values from the connection (the ID of which you also pass to the hook).